# Elastic search Relevance - 5.3

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

Every time I hit the elastic cluster with the same query I get different results(not random either one or the other), I have a 3 node cluster with 2 master eligible nodes. The elastic version is 5.3, has anyone encountered this issue?

Comment: What query are you running ?

Comment: Something like below
`{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "fields": [
              "names.first_name",              
              "names.last_name"
            ],
            "query": "*",
            "default_operator": "AND",
            "analyzer": "standard"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}`

Comment: Are you running this query on an old index or one an index which is being updated currently ? When you say different results can you please elaborate ?

Comment: This is being run on an index which is current. Different results mean that every time i search it via the head plugin i get two results consistently, it keeps on changing, for example always the first document will be A or B. First time i submit the query the result will be A, next time it will be B. Keeps on changing.